# Time Approach Algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, time, sleep

Can anyone shed a little light on how I would go about creating an approach algorithm for a target time; having sleep(x), where x is initially large and decreases as the target time approaches?

Comment: Please could you clarify on what you mean?  Do you mean that you have a loop that calls `sleep()` on each iteration, and you'd like it to use a different value on each iteration?

Comment: How does just sleeping until the target time not meet your requirements?

Comment: @Keith Thompson: sleep not being guaranteed to return exactly when it was specified to, i think he's trying to get a bit more precision out of it.

Comment: It seems like either (a) calling sleep(x) once with x = the total time, or (b) calling sleep with the minimum positive time delay in a loop until you expect to overshoot the mark... are going to be the only two meaningful options. Who cares how many times you call sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void sleep(unsigned long howLong, unsigned decrement)
{
   if (howLong == 0)
      return;
   if (decrement < 2)
   {
      Sleep(howLong);
      return;
   }

   unsigned long delay = howLong / decrement;
   while (delay)
   {
      Sleep(delay);
      delay /= decrement;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your constraints, but an easy solution is to always divide the remaining time by 2 and then sleep for that time. It has logarithmic complexity and that is fine.

Often the OS only guarantees a granularity of 10 ms, so stop sleeping when time falls below 20 ms.